# Is pseudo-class selector :checked supported in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am getting some conflicting answers on this one, so I would like someone to provide some clarification.

Basically according to some sites, :checked is fully supported by Chrome and FF:

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-checked
- http://css3test.com/
- http://tools.css3.info/selectors-test/test.html

However, if you drill into the tests ont the last site, you can notice, that first test is failing on Chrome (v24) and FF (v18), but succeeds on IE10

- http://tools.css3.info/selectors-test/test-checked.html#checked

This minimalistic sample reproduces the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html>
<head>
<style>
      :checked { background-color: royalblue;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" checked />
    <input type="radio"/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</body>
</html>
```

So is :checked pseudo-class supported on Chrome an Firefox (and maybe those just do not allow styling of those elementes) or not?

I am not web designer, so maybe I am missing something simple.

Comment: The tests aren't failing for me on any of those browsers, but I'm guessing in your test case you can't really see `background-color: royalblue` on a radio or checkbox on Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: @BoltClock Good point, I checked with more generic color, same isssue. If you look at the test page, you can see that on IE10 check box in first test has green background, there is no background in Firefox and Chrome. Or is it as expected for some reason?

Comment: @BoltClock: Can you post a jsfiddle? I tried and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: OK, I guess there is nothing wrong with :checked selector, basically FireFox and Chrome does not allow checkboxes or radiobuttons to be styled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put yes they both do.

However the problem you're having stems from the way in which certain browsers render form elements such as checkboxes and radio buttons.

You're unable to see your background color change when the input is selected because the browser is overwriting your customization with it's own default behavior.

Luckily the fix is simple for Chrome, Safari (Webkit) you just need to set an 'appearance:none;' value to wipe out all default styles and then add your own special blend.

Firefox (Gecko) has a known bug associated with rendering checkboxes and radios so you'll get limited use out of the appearance value.

Here's a link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/traxp/

Hope that helps :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            input {
                -webkit-appearance:none;
                -moz-appearance:none;
                appearance:none;
                background:white;
                width:20px;
                height:20px;
                border:2px solid grey;
                border-radius:10px;
            }
            input:checked {
                background:red;  
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="radio" checked />
        <input type="radio"/>
        <input type="checkbox" checked />
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </body>
</html>
```